# How to apply "actionNext" to physic Enter

Tags: android, enter

I'm making a Login Activity which has two EditText, the first one with "actionNext" and the second one with "actionDone".

Everything its ok with the virtual keyboard, because the virtual Enter button is changed to a "Next/Done" button.

But the problem appears with the physical (in AVD) Enter button. Because when I touch it, it makes a breakline in the EditText. Also I tried to use "android:lines="1" but this only makes a "graphical" effect, because the Enter button creates a new breakline also.

This problems appears also when I run the app in my tablet. In my tablet I only have a virtual keyboard, but it has the two buttons (Next and Enter).

How I can get to this "Enter" the "actionNext/actionDone" functionality, or how I can disable this button, to avoid creates new lines.

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my english, i'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` in your Activity

```
@Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

By keyCode you can detect if physic keyboard button Enter was pressed.

Comment: I saw that keyCode of this "physical" Enter is "66".
But if I do:

editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()..
...
onKey(...) {

if (keyCode == 66) {donothing}

}

Its useless because it makes {donothing} and also create a new breakline.

Can you explain better how it runs the "dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) ???

Thanks.

Comment: Documentation says: "Return true if this event was consumed". So you should do: `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { return true; }` More details here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29